# Laravel 5.6: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class env does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, reflection, laravel-5.6

When running my `Laravel 5.6` application on it's production server, I'm getting an error as follows both in the browser and in the console when trying to run artisan commands:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class env does not exist in /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:767
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(767): ReflectionClass->__construct('env')
#1 /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(646): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('env')
#2 /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(601): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('env', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('env', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1210): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->m in /var/www/html/service.straightlinefernie.com/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 767
```

The app runs fine on my development environment. I've combed my `.env` and `config/` files for errors, and it all appears good.

I'm guessing there is something missing in my server set up, but
the main problem as I see it is that this error message is too generic and doesn't provide the information required to discover what specific file or error is actually making the boot process fail.

The stack trace is not even saved in the log file, and appears only in the `console` when I try to run artisan commands.

Does anyone know how to get a more detailed error message that can actually help me solve this error?

Perhaps there is a way to edit the file `Illuminate/Container/Container.php` so that it gives me more info?

Thanks

Comment: For someone still having the issue, it can be solved adding

<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/> in phpunit.xml.

Comment: have you tried `composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I have tried `<env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>` in my phpunit.xml with no success. `composer dunp-autoload -o` also fails with the same error when the post-autoload dump scripts run.

Comment: After one month, i still haven't been able to solve this issue!

Comment: @farooq I don't have TELESCOPE_ENABLED also phpunit.xml file, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `composer dump-autoload -o` and `php artisan config:clear` doesn't work then check your `.env` for potential errors like this:

```
KEY=THE VALUE
```

Should be

```
KEY="THE VALUE"
```

Comment: Errors in the .env weren't my problem, but I'll accept this answer, since I'm sure it will be helpful to others. The only way I was able to get past my particular error was to rm -rf the whole project directory and re-deploy the app in a clean environment. I would still love to know if there is any way to get a more useful error message when Laravel fails during the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and found issue in config folder > constants file I was wrote "asset('/')" and "url()" function in config file, we can't write such functions in config.

Hope this answer will some one who stuck like this errors.